# How can I pass the user input number from EditText and set it on the 2nd number in for each inside my _createListView()?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I pass the user input number from EditText in android and set it on the 2nd number in for statement inside my `_createListView()`?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView _listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int int_text = intent.getIntExtra("name", 100);

        this._listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        this._createListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void _createListView() {
        List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100  ; i++) {
            String indexAsString = String.valueOf(i);
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                rowItems.add(new RowItem(indexAsString, "FizzBuzz"));
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                rowItems.add(new RowItem(indexAsString, "Fizz"));
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                rowItems.add(new RowItem(indexAsString, "Buzz"));
            } else {
                rowItems.add(new RowItem(indexAsString, indexAsString));
            }
        }

        RowItemArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new RowItemArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_main_list_row, rowItems);
        this._listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private static class RowItem {
        private String _index;
        private String _value;

        public RowItem(String index, String value) {
            this._index = index;
            this._value = value;
        }

        public String getIndex() {
            return this._index;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this._value;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView indexTextView;
        public TextView valueTextView;
    }

    private static class RowItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

        private LayoutInflater _layoutInflater;
        private int _textViewResourceId;

        public RowItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<RowItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, resource, objects);

            this._layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this._textViewResourceId = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) this.getItem(position);
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = this._layoutInflater.inflate(this._textViewResourceId, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.indexTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.index);
                viewHolder.valueTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.indexTextView.setText(rowItem.getIndex());
            viewHolder.valueTextView.setText(rowItem.getValue());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value in a string and call it whereever you want orelse if you want to store it somewhere use `sharedpreference`.

Store values with `sharedpreference` :

```
SharedPreference mypref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("name_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= mypref.edit();
                editor.putString("name_key",name_string);
                editor.apply();
```

To retrieve it from anywhere in your program:

```
 SharedPreference mypref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("name_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String av = mypref.getString("name","");
```